# Threads trying to acquire pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) What happens if they don't get the lock?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, locks

C Programming:

What happens when a thread tries to acquire a mutex lock, and fails to get it?

Does it go to sleep?

Will the thread be woken up when pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); is called?

Then try to obtain the lock again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3.html):

> The **`pthread_mutex_lock()`** function locks *mutex*.  If the mutex is already locked, the calling thread will block until the mutex becomes available.

So yes - your thread is blocked until the lock is available and it can obtain it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a blocking call and will block until it gets the lock.

The non-blocking version is `pthread_mutex_trylock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex)` and will return `EBUSY` if someone else has the lock, or `0` if it got the lock. (Or some other error, of course)

Answer (score 3):

Normally, `pthread_mutex_lock` cannot return until it acquires the lock, even if this means that it never returns (deadlock). There are a few notable exceptions though:

- For recursive mutexes, it can return `EAGAIN` if the maximum reference count would be exceeded.
- For error-checking mutexes, it can return `EDEADLK` if the thread tries to lock a mutex it already holds a lock on.
- For robust mutexes, it can return `EOWNERDEAD` if another process died while holding the (shared) mutex. In this case, despite getting an error return, the caller holds the mutex lock and can mark the mutex-protected state valid again by calling `pthread_mutex_consistent`.
- For robust mutexes whose owner died and for which the new owner called `pthread_mutex_unlock` without calling `pthread_mutex_consistent` first, it will return `ENOTRECOVERABLE`.

There may be a few cases I missed. Note that none of these apply to normal mutexes (`PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL` type) without the robust attribute set, so if you only use normal mutexes, you can reasonably assume the call never returns without succeeding.

Answer (score 0):

From the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html):

> If the mutex is already locked, the calling thread shall block until the mutex becomes available.
>
> (...)
>
> If there are threads blocked on the mutex object referenced by `mutex` when `pthread_mutex_unlock()` is called, resulting in the mutex becoming available, the scheduling policy shall determine which thread shall acquire the mutex.

Where the "resulting in" clause is necessary because

> (In the case of `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` mutexes, the mutex shall become available when the count reaches zero and the calling thread no longer has any locks on this mutex.)